# Calling variable in one class file to another file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm a newbie in python programming. Please help me with this problem in python3:

pack.py

```py
class one:

    def test(self):
        number = 100   ######I want to access this value and how?
        print('test')

class two:

    def sample(self):
        print('sample')
```

another.py

```py
from pack import *

class three:

    def four(self):
        obj = one()
        print(obj.test())

###### I want to access the number value in this file and i don't know how #######

obj = three()
obj.four()
```

Comment: These are not classes but functions.

Comment: First, you might be confusing classes and functions. Secondly, I guess you are asking about imports, but I am not sure. Can you clarify?

Comment: I ask both @tst both are implement in one

Comment: ``number`` is a function's *local* variable. It's not part of any class, and doesn't even exist unless the function is being executed. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi am not come to achieve anything i have doubt so i asked question.  Thx for answering my question :)

Comment: I mean what are you trying to do? Accessing a function's local isn't really useful. *Why* are you trying to access ``number``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  If access the variable inone file  class inside the function to another file is easy to reuse so i asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative
pack.py

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 100

    def test(self):
        print('test')

class Two:
    def sample(self):
        print('Sample')
```

another.py

```
from pack import *

class Three:
    def four(self):
        self.obj = One().number
        return self.obj

three = Three().four()
print(three)
```

By what seems to be your approach, you were using classes to access variables. It is better to instantiate variables in a constructor ( **init**  method in class **One**). Then import the class and access it in another class of another file.

Also, it is a good practice to name classes beginning with uppercase letters. There are more possible ways but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`number` needs to be in a global scope, that means outside of a function definition (it shouldn't be indented)

if the variable is inside a function it is impossible to get it in another file

pack.py

```py
number = 100
def test():
   test.other_number = 999 # here we assigne a variable to the function object.
   print("test")
```

another.py

```py
import pack

pack.test()
print(pack.number)

print(test.other_number) # this only works if the function has been called once
```

Alternatively if you are using classes:

pack.py

```py
class Someclass():
    other_number = 999 # here we define a class variable

    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 100 # here we set the number to be saved in the class

    def test(self):
        print(self.number) # here we print the number
```

another.py

```py
import pack

somclass_instance = pack.Someclass() # we make a new instance of the class. this runs the code in __init__
somclass_instance.test() # here we call the test method of Someclass
print(somclass_instance.number) # and here we get the number

print(Someclass.other_number) # here we retrieve the class variable
```

Comment: yeah i know this method but otherwise any other method to call the value like same

Comment: @vraj i added in how to use a class variable for this, class variables are accessible from Class and instance of that class. ive also added a example for adding variables to the function object

Comment: I dont understand why we are allowed to assign an attribute to a function object?

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL: Because why not? It's unusual, but functions need attributes already (e.g. their docstrings), so they were allowed to support arbitrary attributes.

Comment: Well, complex numbers need attributes too, but we cant assing a new attribute to them. I wonder is there any document about that.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL python is a "consenting adults laguage" which means youre allowed to do everything, like there also is no private variables in python for the same reason.

Comment: @vraj could you accept my answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: @laundmo I know, but we are not allowed to do everthing.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL what is there that python just doesnt allow. of course there are a few things that are hard to do, but what is forbidden by python?

Comment: Okay, okay I know python well. I know it is so free too but also you know that we can't do everything.

Comment: @vraj there is a tickmark below the score of my answer, if you could click that. it marks this question as solved. screenshot example: https://i.vgy.me/sJbNeJ.png

Comment: @laundmo add this line "By what seems to be your approach, you were using classes to access variables. It is better to instantiate variables in a constructor ( init method in class One). Then import the class and access it in another class of another file.

Also, it is a good practice to name classes beginning with uppercase letters. There are more possible ways but hope it helps." by deba-m